# Can I Use Paypal REST API in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I want to use the Paypal REST API in my titanium app, I write code like this :

```
function paypal(){
var data = {grant_type: 'client_credentials'};
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function() {
        alert(this.responseText);
    },
    onerror: function(e) {
        alert(e.error);
    },
    timeout : 5000
});
xhr.open('POST', 'https://clientID:secret@api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language','en_us');
xhr.send(data);
}
```

But it keep response as error and said : Authentication Needed 
Can anybody give me a help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a titanium module for [Paypal](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/blob/master/paypal/mobile/android/documentation/index.md) , so you can use it easily.

Comment: I know, already work out on it. But I prefer to use the REST API more.
Whatever thank you for your suggestion